# If I know most of the clear text, can I crack AES?

Tags: aes

To be specific, suppose that AES_256_CBC is used (the key is 32 bytes, the iv is 16 bytes) and that the text is about 500 bytes, but most of the text is known to me. Consider an extreme case, only 1 byte of it, I do not know.

And suppose the message head (the first 32 bytes) does not contain that byte.

Can I crack this? I mean whether I can find out what that unknown byte is.

Comment: This would be more appropriate on either a crypto/security site, or cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This would probably be a better question for [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: so many websites, so complicated, I am not able to handle it. I did try to use crypto/security site, but I have no id there.